# iPhone - ABPeoplePickerNavigationController: Show "Phone" properties but not the Ringtone

Tags: iphone, contacts, peoplepicker

Using the code below, I'm bringing up a person picker so the user can choose either a phone or an email address.  I've set the displayable properties to Email and Phone, but the "Ringtone" property is visible in the phone group.  Given the purpose of this instance of Person picker, the Ringtone choice makes absolutely no sense to display here.  Anyone know how to get rid of it in the phone group?

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

NSArray *propertiesToShow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil];

[picker setDisplayedProperties:propertiesToShow];

[picker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: I second that. I suppose the Phone property includes ringtones, and there's no separate ringtone property at the moment. Might need to submit this one to Apple. (I'm stopping short of posting this as an answer because I'm not 100% certain on this point.)